# Key but not mouse event received in pygame display embedded in GTK+ widget

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, pygtk

I'm embedding a pygame display in a GTK widget to implement debug controls for a game prototype.

It seems I'm forced to use PyGTK to handle the inputs for the game. My callbacks receive the gtk key-press-events, but button-press-events never makes it.

```
class Dashboard():
[...]
self.drawingarea_game = gtk.DrawingArea()
self.drawingarea_game.set_flags(gtk.CAN_DEFAULT | gtk.CAN_FOCUS | gtk.SENSITIVE | gtk.PARENT_SENSITIVE)
gobject.timeout_add(60, game.test_loop)
self.win.show_all()
self.drawingarea_game.grab_focus()
self.drawingarea_game.connect("button-press-event", game.mousepress)
self.drawingarea_game.connect("key-press-event", game.keypress)
gtk.main()


class Game():
[...]
def keypress(self, widget, event):
    Error.log(event.keyval)
    if event.keyval == 100: #d
        self.SCREEN_POSITION_X = -30
    if event.keyval == 97:  #a
        self.SCREEN_POSITION_X = 0
    if event.keyval == 115: #s
        self.SCREEN_POSITION_Y = -30
    if event.keyval == 119: #w
        self.SCREEN_POSITION_Y = 0
    return True

def mousepress(self, widget, event):
    Error.log(event.button)
```

I also tried checking for a pygame event, in case it somehow got hijacked, but that doesn't report anything either:

```
class Game():
[...]
def test_loop(self):
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        print(event)
```

The drawing area is nested so: Window -> HBox -> VBox

I have a couple of buttons elsewhere in the window that receive clicks fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mouse event has to be ***explicitly*** declared for the drawing area, apparently in contrast to the keystroke event. It works after adding:

```
self.drawingarea_game.set_events(gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK)
```